# python re how to give space after specific word?

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to add space after word *'Flavor'* but getting space after every letter.
Here is my code:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=["Flavor"])(?=[^\s])', r' ', short_description)
```

My Python shell result:

```
>>> 'F l a v o r BLACKWATER OG (I), APPLE JACK (S), BLACKBERRY KUSH (I), SOUR TANGIE (S), SUNSET GELATO (H)'
```

I am expected to get this result:

```
>>> 'Flavor BLACKWATER OG (I), APPLE JACK (S), BLACKBERRY KUSH (I), SOUR TANGIE (S), SUNSET GELATO (H)'
```

Comment: Why not just `short_description.replace('Flavor','Flavor ')`?  It's not really a regex problem.

Comment: @Tim Roberts thanks for the suggestion but can we do it in   regex?

Comment: I second Tim. The specific problem in your code is that `[chars]` means "any of `c`,`h`,`a`,`r`,`s`". If you want to match the text exactly, use `chars` (without the square braces).

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?<=Flavor\s)', r' ', short_description)` or just `re.sub(r'(?<=Flavor )', r' ', short_description)`

Comment: You should not use a regex unless you need a regex.  Regular expressions are expensive compared to simple string searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.sub` with a regex shown below to replace every occurrence of `Flavor` followed by 0 or more whitespace characters with `Flavor`  (which has exactly 1 blank after `Flavor`):

```
import re
short_descriptions = [
    'FlavorBLACKWATER OG',
    'Flavor BLACKWATER OG',
    'Flavor  BLACKWATER OG'
]
for short_description in short_descriptions:
    print(re.sub(r'Flavor\s*', r'Flavor ', short_description))
```

Prints:

```
Flavor BLACKWATER OG
Flavor BLACKWATER OG
Flavor BLACKWATER OG
```

Note that the regex above avoids the lookbehind (`(?<=Flavor )`) completely.
Also note that as the commenters above mentioned, the regex you were using specifies a character class `["Flavor"]`, so adds a blank after any of these specified characters: `", F, l, a, v, o, r`.